# Java's BigInteger toString method not returning a (non-empty) String for large integers

Tags: java, eclipse

My aim to to find the exact numerical value of an extremely large integer and print it to a file, console, or anything else that allows me to view the beginning. The following is my code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        BigInteger bigValueToPrint = BigInteger.valueOf ( 107 ).pow ( 82798 );
        System.out.println ( bigValueToPrint.toString() );
    }
}
```

However, this is not printing out anything. I have also tried writing the string to a file and reading the file to see if this would help, however it did not.

I also tried, instead of using `BigInteger's pow()` method, creating a loop that, on each run through the loop, multiplies the `bigValueToPrint` by `107`, starting at `107`, and printing this number out in each loop. However, it quickly stops printing out (although at this point it will still have many many digits).

Comment: Your code executed for me and printed 827989405809.... in console.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me as well.

Comment: Your example is actually working for me. It prints out `8279894058094115681...9028188888147094115791049`. An Integer with 168030 digits. This seems to be related to your environment. I'm using JDK 1.8.0_77 64bit on OSX 10.11.15 (64bit).

Comment: Oh, how bizarre. I'm using Eclipse and tried opening the file in Eclipse when I tried writing to a file, both of which did not work. It opens fine in an external text editor, so it appears that Eclipse was at fault.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlexW Some editors don't like *very* long lines of text.

Comment: yes, at home, eclipse begins howling from `BigInteger.valueOf (107).pow (1614)`, which is coded in in a string of 3276 char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own questions (with the answer learnt from the comments), Eclipse cannot be relied on to print arbitrarily large values in its console; such code simply works perfectly but displays imperfectly in Eclipse. It displays perfectly in a console.